# how can I hide an empty tableview

Tags: ios

I have a problem and I hope someone here can help me out! Thanks in advance.

I have a "Scope"button(see screen shot!) which is linked to a segue and the segue goes to a tableview.

[image]

What I want to do is in the tableview controller that I decide if I should display something in the table or I should throw out an alertview.

What I did was:

```
if ([_countryScopes count] == 0) {

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    //no scope for this country
    NSMutableString *message = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"No scope information."];
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:countryName message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    //av.tag = MAIN_ALERT;
    [av show];


}
```

But somehow the empty table is still showing up.

Do you know, how I can get rid of this?

Thanks a lot!

Regards, Yashu

Comment: Could you post your method that is executed when you press Scope button? You could check there wether to show something or to display an alert.

Comment: Hi Alex, when the "Scope" button is pressed, the prepareForSegue is called. `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showScope"]) {
        //self.scopeTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        //self.scopeTableViewController.passedFromMasterItem = _passedFromMasterItem;
        
        //[self.scopeTableViewController prepareViewController];
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

just show alert view after 0.1 seconds, i hope this will do the trick:

```
[av performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```